# Using a ps3 controller to play Lego Star Wars on PC

Tags: controllers, motioninjoy-ds3tool, lego-star-wars

I'm trying to use a PS3 controller to play Lego Star Wars The Complete Saga on PC. I managed to use "DS3 Tool" to connect the PS3 controller. As far as I could tell this worked fine; I could bring up the Windows calibration dialog and calibrate the controller. But when I started the game and tried to use the controller it didn't work: the in-game controller select menu didn't react when I was instructed to press a button on the controller.

Any clues?

Comment: Seems like a lot of bugginess surrounds the DS3Tool, just by googling around.  Most games will only look for controllers using a particular interface, so unless the DS3Tools programmers used something common, such as, say, DirectInput (and they may have, I couldn't find any definitive info without using valuable starcraft time), then it's possible it won't find it.  I saw on a screenshot an option to have the sixaxis emulate a 360 controller, which is where I would start, I think.  If you can get it to work as a 360 controller, there are tools out there for mapping that to the keyboard.

Comment: I actually managed to get the DS3Tool to work by telling it to emulate a 360-controller. But after a while it just stopped working. Would a real 360-controller just work out-of-the-box, or would I need some extra driver for that?

Comment: There is an XInput driver for the 360 controller that needs to be installed for it to support everything the xbox can do (up to 4 controllers connected, triggers work properly, other things i'm sure), which can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8682 .  I would install it if you're having problems, but who knows if it's needed or not.  Not having a sixaxis controller myself, I don't know if that's the issue you're having or not.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried MotioninJoy?

Description:

> MotioninJoy is a driver, designed by a developer unconnected with
>   Sony, intended to use all the features of the Sixaxis and Dualshock 3
>   controllers on a PC running Windows.

Info: http://www.motioninjoy.com/wiki/en/whatis

Comment: Yes, I tried MotionInJoy, but it was pretty shaky. The GUI was unresponsive 10-20 seconds at a time, and when I got the controller up and running it would suddenly stop working in the middle of the game. That's a showstopper when you have a 6yo who wants to play...

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest version of motionjoy (060001) and set the ps3 controllers up to emulate xbox controllers.
works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

MotionJoy probably works, but I prefer open sourced [ScpToolkit](https://github.com/nefarius/ScpToolkit) which also doesn't show any ads. Install drivers for you ps3/ps4 controller with it, but then don't forget to install xbox controller drivers, which will also virtually map ps3 controls to xbox controls. They only inconvenience is that you'll see xbox style button names A/B/X/Y instead of X/O/square/triangle